# Python Tkinter - destroy window after time or on click

Tags: python, tkinter, window, messagebox

I have following code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

try:
    w = tk.Tk()
    w.after(3000, lambda: w.destroy()) # Destroy the widget after 3 seconds
    w.withdraw()
    messagebox.showinfo('MONEY', 'MORE MONEY')
    if messagebox.OK:
        w.destroy()
    w.mainloop()
    confirmation = 'Messagebox showed'
    print(confirmation)
except Exception:
    confirmation = 'Messagebox showed'
    print(confirmation)
```

Is there better way to do this, without using threading and catching exception?

Comment: I think this question woud rather be asked in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @figbeam No, this is an MCVE. Those are off-topic at Code Review. Please take a look at their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is your actual use case that you need to destroy a window in such a manner? You can't do this in a good manner without the exception catching. If it can throw, you need to be able to catch it. At least, you should. Or your user won't be happy.

Comment: I try to get a message box window, which can be closed after time 't', or faster, when user click an "OK" button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `if messagebox.OK:`, but `messagebox.OK` is defined as `OK = "ok"`. Therefore, your if statement is always true. If you want to check whether the user clicked the button you need to get the return value of the `showinfo` function.

So you can do:

```
a = messagebox.showinfo('MONEY', 'MORE MONEY')
if a:
    w.destroy()
```

Or even shorter:

```
if messagebox.showinfo('MONEY', 'MORE MONEY'):
    w.destroy()
```

This way `w.destroy` is not run when the user didn't click anything (so when `w.destroy` has already been run by the `after` call).

In total:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

w = tk.Tk()
w.withdraw()
w.after(3000, w.destroy) # Destroy the widget after 3 seconds
if messagebox.showinfo('MONEY', 'MORE MONEY'):
    w.destroy()

confirmation = 'Messagebox showed'
print(confirmation)
```

Comment: Exactly this what I need!