# tKmessagebox automatic selection after a timeout

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I want to display a messagebox with options Yes or No. If user doesn't select any option with in the TIMEOUT(ex:5 sec) Messagebox should be closed with default YES option . How can i achieve it ?

Below is the code i used but it `resp` value is always False.

```
    from Tkinter import *
    import tkMessageBox

    time = 2000
    def status():
       resp=True
       root.destroy()
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    root.after(time,status)
    resp=tkMessageBox.askyesno(title='Test',message='Click Yes otherwise No',default=tkMessageBox.YES)
    print resp
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51651826/3714930

Comment: Here i want to close only MessageBox .Root shouldn't be destroyed . Is there anyway to destroy only tkMessageBox??

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible because you don't get a reference to the actual dialog window, you'd have to create your own [custom dialog window](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm).

Answer (score 2):

With the default `askyesno` messagebox you cannot do this. You can do this with a custom dialog like for example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MyDialog(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent, text):

        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Label(self, text=text).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=50, pady=10)

        b_yes = tk.Button(self, text="Yes", command=self.yes, width=8)
        b_yes.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        b_no = tk.Button(self, text="No", command=self.no, width=8)
        b_no.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.answer = None
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.no)

    def yes(self):
        self.answer = "Yes"
        self.destroy()

    def no(self):
        self.answer = "No"
        self.destroy()

def popup():
    d = MyDialog(root, "Click Yes or No")
    root.after(5000, d.yes)
    root.wait_window(d)  
    print d.answer

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text="Show popup", command=popup).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks @fhdrsdg . I will go with Custom window method

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you. If you haven't already, please read the help page on [what you can do when you get an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).